# Getting a specific TUPLE and returning it sql

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get the rate to bill a customer from a table that isn't directly related to it and any type of join doesn't seem to want to work with an Alter table statement.

I have 4 tables:

- Venue
- AllEvents
- DesiredStaffLevel
- EventBill

`AllEvents.EVENTID` is a foreign key in all the other tables.

`DesiredStaffLevel` has a calculated column for the total number of hours worked called `TotalManHours` that I want to use in the `EventBill`

`Venue` has a variable called `VenueRate` that I would like to use in the event bill  (venue is a fk in `AllEvents`)

So what I want is the Sum of TotalManHours Multiplied By The venueRate.

My problem is that the venuerate is linked   the Allevents table by a venue ID and the eventid key links to the eventbill and desired staff level.

I thought something like this would work but it doesn't. I think its because it can't find the specific VENUEID/VenueRate but I'm not really sure.

```
Select Sum(DesiredStaffLevel.TotalManHours)AS TotalHours

     From DesiredStaffLevel

     Join AllEvents ON eventID = EventIDFK

      For EventID !=  null(

      Alter Table EventBill

      ADD EstCharge  ASSum(TotalManHours * VenueRate)    

      Group BY eventIdfk;

      )
```

Comment: Wait...which RBDMS are you using?  MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: How can we use Alter Table in Select query? Strange.. 
Do you want to generate Column EstCharge in Event Bill Table depending upon some condition?

Comment: yes the venuerate where the event occurs

Comment: Your question is not well laid out, the table structure is nearly incomprehensible, and there is no sample data or desired result.  Tips on how to ask a question: basics: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and for more info:  http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ (note the "sample code and data")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am resorting to an answer instead of a comment because I need formatting to help explain.

In SQL you do NOT combine *alter table* inside a *select* query. It is far more likely that you need an **UPDATE QUERY** and that you do not need *alter table*.

However your description of your existing tables is incomplete and difficult to understand. What you need to do is supply the table name, then list the column names, and then some sample data for each table separately.

**For Example**

---

```
AllEvents
EVENTIDFK, VENUEIDFK, EventDate,  EventName
1,         88,        2016-01-17, VIP 60th Birthday

Venue
VENUEID, VenueRate 
88,      12.12

DesiredStaffLevel
EVENTIDFK, TotalManHours
1,         100

EventBill
EVENTIDFK, EstCharge
1,
```

Then by using query:

```
SELECT
      ae.EVENTID
    , v.VENUEID
    , v.VenueRate
    , dse.TotalManHours
    , (dse.TotalManHours * v.VenueRate) AS CalculatedBill
FROM AllEvents AS ae
      INNER JOIN Venue AS v ON ae.VENUEIDFK = v.VENUEID
      INNER JOIN DesiredStaffLevel AS dse ON ae.EVENTID = dse.EVENTIDFK
;
```

Which provides this result:

```
| EVENTID | VENUEID | VenueRate | TotalManHours | CalculatedBill |
|---------|---------|-----------|---------------|----------------|
|       1 |      88 |     12.12 |           100 |        1212.00 |
```

How can you get that calculation into the Table EventBill?

---

Use an UPDATE like this:

```
UPDATE
      EventBill
SET EstCharge = dt.CalculatedBill
FROM EventBill
      INNER JOIN (
            SELECT
                  ae.EVENTID
                , SUM(dse.TotalManHours * v.VenueRate) AS CalculatedBill
            FROM AllEvents AS ae
                  INNER JOIN Venue AS v ON ae.VENUEIDFK = v.VENUEID
                  INNER JOIN DesiredStaffLevel AS dse ON ae.EVENTID = dse.EVENTIDFK
            GROUP BY
                  ae.EVENTID
      ) AS dt ON EventBill.EVENTIDFK = dt.EVENTID
;
```

Then inspect the outcome using a simple select

```
SELECT
      *
FROM EventBill
;
```

and the result is:

```
| EVENTIDFK | EstCharge |
|-----------|-----------|
|         1 |   1212.00 |
```

Here is a working demonstration (at sqlfiddle) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/31f09/2

Comment: Please note that this "answer" is an attempt to show how to layout the question. **The data model and data used above is pure fiction** and I do not know how close (or far) it is from the actual requirements.

Comment: I will definitely keep the formatting in mind in the future.  I'm pretty new to all this. But using update works better than alter. I was running under the assumption I could only make a table calculated if it was new hence the alter and not update.

Comment: It isn't just formatting that is important. It is **necessary** to provide sample data and the "expected result". If you do both of those then it will be so much easier for you to communicate what it is that you need; and it is easier for us to answer, and so you get the answer faster. Also I suggest get familiar with http://sqlfiddle.com it can help you answer your own problems or we can assist and use it for the tables & sample data